# Use cursor values used in HTML Drag and Drop API

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I'd like to use the same cursor icons used in HTML Drag and Drop API (DataTransfer.dropEffect property copy and none), however, currently i'm using the jquery draggable/droppable api. Is it possible to set the cursor to these values without having to change the api i use?

Neither of the cursor icons appear to be specified anywhere in the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Here is an example of what I'd like the cursor behavior to be: https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/drag-and-drop/copy-move-DataTransfer.html

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Have a look at this article on how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hey jtate, what sort of example would you want? I'm just curious to know if i can use those cursor icons in the jquery draggable api, as they dont appear to be in the cursor property spec i posted above. Don't think an example is relevant. jquery draggable api is working as i expect, i just want to know if/how i can use those icons.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community!

Get the html element of the drag and drop component and style that component using CSS.

```
div[draggable] {
  background-color: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answer, but this isn't what i'm looking for. i've updated the question to include an example of the cursor icon behavior i'm looking for as maybe i was not clear